# Proguard Enabling in eclipse

Tags: android, apk

I would like to use proguard in my application. Can anyone tell me the steps should I follow to create the cfg file. Like what is the first step I have to do, where should I create the file..etc

Comment: A little googling will give the solution...

Answer (score 2):

On Android Developer's site there is a great documentation:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

In short:

In your project directory find project.properties file. You should have similar line:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt:proguard-google-api-client.txt
```

In txt files you should have proguard configuration.

You should know one thing that proguard is disable (by default) if you run application in debug mode. Proguard will "start" while exporting signed app.

Comment: but I am not able to fine proguard.cfg file in my project

Comment: Do you have proguard directory in your SDK tools? proguard-project.txt is simple text file with proguard config. If you have proguard.config line in your project.properties proguard will look at this file.

Comment: If you want to use proguard.cfg file - create such a file in your root project directory and set proguard.config=proguard.cfg

Comment: yea I did that. but at the time of exporting its giving some errors.

Comment: So it's working :) Google those errors. Configuring project for proguard is sometimes time consuming.

Comment: +1 for "You should know one thing that proguard is disable (by default) if you run application in debug mode. Proguard will "start" while exporting signed app."